# Call to undefined method Base::grab() [fat-free framework]

Tags: php, cron, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to set-up a cronjob. 
I have followed [this](https://github.com/xfra35/f3-cron) tutorial here on configuring cronjob with fat-free framework. 
I have put "cron.php" file in "path/to/app/lib" folder.
And my index.php file is :

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$f3 = require('lib/base.php');
$cron = Cron::instance();
$cron->set('lunchAlert','GBD\Internals\Controllers\LunchController->sendAlertNotificationsUsers','* * * * *');

$f3->run();
```

Here's my controller script:

```
public function sendAlertNotificationsUsers()
{
    echo "hello world";
}
```

Here's how I installed my job in crontab:

```
crontab -e

* * * * * cd /var/www/html/dev-portal-new; php index.php /cron
```

But I'm getting this mail :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Base::grab() in /var/www/html/dev-portal-new/lib/cron.php on line 110
HTTP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Base::grab() (GET /cron)
```

What do I do to add this Base::grab() method? 
Anyone here on fat-free framework? Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're obviously using an old version of the framework. The `grab()` method has been introduced in version 3.5. See https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: thank you. Is there any way that I add that grab() function in my old lib/base.php?

Comment: Sure: just copy the [grab()](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/10f97fb756b42d82ccdc02ad8054a1af8b589c83/base.php#L1753) method.